# How to check if a string inside of an array,contains a part of a string in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
$arr = array("Hello_backup","World!","Beautiful_backup","Day!");
if(in_array("backup", $arr)){
    echo "Da";
} else { echo "Nu";
}
```

But is not working because,in_array instruction check the array for the complete string "backup" , which doesnt exist.I need to check for a part of the string,for example,to return true because backup is a part of the "Hello_backup" and "Beautiful_backup" strings

**EDIT:** I take the advice and i have used stripos like this:

```
$arr = array("Hello_backup-2014","World!","Beautiful_backup-2014","Day!");
$word='backup';
if(stripos($arr,$word) !== false){
echo "Da";
} else { echo "Nu";}
```

but now i get an error: "stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in if(stripos($arr,$word) !== false){"

Comment: Your error comes from the fact that you are trying to use an array as if it was a string. You need to use `foreach` on your array to get every string that this array contains. Take a better look at @Ghost example.

Comment: @Lght not necessarily, if you want to treat all array values as one, you can use implode to join the array elements as a string. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to basically concatenate the array values as a string, then use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check for a string within a string.

The first argument you pass to implode is used to separate each value in the array.

```
$array = array("Hello_backup","World!","Beautiful_backup","Day!");
$r = implode(" ", $array);

if (strpos($r, "backup") !== false) {
    echo "found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to use `stripos()`. Example:

```
$arr = array("Hello_backup","World!","Beautiful_backup","Day!");
$needle = 'backup';

function check($haystack, $needle) {
    foreach($haystack as $word) {
        if(stripos($word, $needle) !== false) {
            return 'Da!'; // if found
        }
    }
    return 'Nu'; // if not found
}

var_dump(check($arr, $needle));
```

Without a function:

```
$arr = array("Hello_backup","World!","Beautiful_backup","Day!");

$found = false;
foreach($arr as $word) {
    if(stripos($word, 'backup') !== false) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($found) {
    echo 'Da!';
} else {
    echo 'Nu';
}
```

Comment: an example without the function please? i am a beginner and i dont want to use functions yet

Comment: i have an error stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array

Comment: @Memphistoles if you do not want a function, check my revision

Comment: @Memphistoles no you cannot use `stripos` directly, you must loop it first (each string) dont use the whole array, check my revision

Answer (score 1):

Use this method. It is little bit simple to use.

```
$matches = preg_grep('/backup/', $arr); 
$keys    = array_keys($matches);     
print_r($matches);
```

Look this [working example](http://codepad.org/57nJNGLl)

According to your question

```
$matches = preg_grep('/backup/', $arr); 
$keys    = array_keys($matches);         
$matches = trim($matches);    
if($matches != '')
{echo "Da";
}else { echo "Nu";}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $arr = array("Hello_backup","World!","Beautiful_backup","Day!");
    foreach($arr as $arr1) {
        if (strpos ($arr1,"backup")) {
            echo "Da";
        } else {
            echo "Nu";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `strpos()`

```
$arr = array("Hello_backup","World!","Beautiful_backup","Day!");
foreach($arr as $v){
  echo (strpos($v,"backup")!== false ? "Da" : "Nu");
}
```

output :- `DaNuDaNu`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one line solution for you.

```
$arr = array("Hello_backup-2014","World!","Beautiful_backup-2014","Day!");

$returned_a = array_map(function($u){ if(stripos($u,'backup') !== false) return  "Da"; else return "Nu";}, $arr);
```

You can use $returned_a with array as your answer..
`Array ( [0] => Da [1] => Nu [2] => Da [3] => Nu )`